# Solving algebraic Riccati Like equation using Newtons method

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

I am trying to solve the following equation for $P$

$0=X(t)^{\rm T}\left(Y^{\rm T}P+PY-\gamma P-PZR^{-1}Z^{\rm
T}P+S^{\rm T}QS\right)X(t)+\mu^{\rm T}R\mu,$

where $Y\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $Z\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$, $C\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$, $R\in\mathbb{R}$, $P\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$. $Y$, $\gamma$, $Z$,$S$,$\mu$, $R$ are known.

we can solve the case

$0=X(t)^{\rm T}\left(Y^{\rm T}P+PY-\gamma P-PZR^{-1}Z^{\rm
T}P+S^{\rm T}QS\right)X(t)$ as it is exactly an algebraic Ricatti equation, and can be solved using iterative methods such as Newtons method as depicted in "On an Iterative Technique for Riccati
Equation Computations" by D. Klienman http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1098829&tag=1ftp://ftp.math.ucla.edu/pub/camreport/cam05-15.pdf.

but with extra term $\mu^{\rm T}R\mu$, I am stuck. I am trying to figure out what additonal steps do I need to do to solve the equation by using the same  iterative newton method with the extra term $\mu^{\rm T}R\mu$ along with the algebraic Ricatti equation. Appreciate any ideas, hints or help :).

Comment: If you want to use a numerical method, why not try it and see if it works?

Comment: @Pait, thank you for your response. Yes, I will try it using Newtons method. However, can you please share your insight regarding solving such equations in general? I guess with my relatively less experience that, it is difficult to solve Lyapunov  or Riccati  with varaitions...i.e Sylvesters equations with variations...Apart from using Newtons method in specific have you ever come across any easy way to solve the equation mentioned in my question? Highly appreciate any thoughts, hints...Thank you for your time and efforts

Comment: Try starting with low-dimensional cases to develop intuition. It's a generalization of the garden-variety quadratic equation after all. The name "Riccati" equation is not only a misnomer, it's misleading.